# how to get last and secondlast record.? and how to use it in as sub query.?

Tags: mysql, logic

```
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
| id |        user_email       | cat_id | sub_cat_id | score | out_of | score_in_per | date       |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
| 13 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 40    | 40     | 100          | 22-04-2017 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
| 14 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 37    | 40     | 92.5         | 22-04-2017 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
| 26 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 36    | 40     | 88           | 23-04-2017 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
| 27 | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | 35    | 40     | 80           | 23-04-2017 |
+----+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------------+
```

From above table i want to get the record like this can anyone help me/

```
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------+
| lastScore | secondLastScore | maxPortaScore |        user_email       | cat_id | sub_cat_id | score | out_of | score_in_per | date |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------+
| 80        | 88              | 100           | inststudent@yopmail.com | 9      | 11         | -     | -      | -            | -    |
+-----------+-----------------+---------------+-------------------------+--------+------------+-------+--------+--------------+------+
```

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
scor.id,
(SELECT score_in_per 
FROM tbl_student_skill_score 
WHERE cat_id = scor.cat_id and sub_cat_id = scor.sub_cat_id and scor.user_email='inststudent@yopmail.com'
ORDER BY scor.date DESC,scor.id DESC LIMIT 1)
as lastScore,

(SELECT score_in_per 
FROM tbl_student_skill_score
WHERE cat_id=scor.cat_id and sub_cat_id=scor.sub_cat_id and scor.user_email='inststudent@yopmail.com' 
ORDER BY scor.date DESC,scor.id DESC LIMIT 1,1)
as secondLastScore,

(SELECT max(cast(score_in_per as decimal(5,2))) 
FROM tbl_student_skill_score 
WHERE cat_id = scor.cat_id and sub_cat_id=scor.sub_cat_id) 
as maxPortaScore,

scor.user_email,scor.cat_id,
scor.sub_cat_id,scor.score, scor.out_of,
scor.score_in_per,scor.date
FROM 
tbl_student_skill_score scor 
LEFT JOIN 
tbl_skilltest_subcategory subc 
ON 
scor .sub_cat_id = subc.scat_id 
LEFT JOIN 
tbl_skilltest_category catg 
ON subc.cat_id = catg.id 
where 
scor.user_email = 'inststudent@yopmail.com'
GROUP BY 
sub_cat_id 
ORDER by 
scor.id DESC,scor.date DESC
```

Form the above Query **lastScore** and **secondLastScore** are not working

**lastScore** means the last stored record in my case from 1st table it is `id`:27 record.  so the result should be**80**

similarly

**secondLastScore**  means the second last stored record in my case from 1st table it is `id`:26 record.  so the result should be **88**

**maxPortaScore** means the max score of that particular category across the table it is not relates to the particular student in my case it is **100**
i have used the same user for example but actually it can be any user score.**[THIS IS WORKING ABSOLUTLY FINE]**

Comment: What if user (email) have only one record? then what would be `secondLastScore` value ?

Comment: `secondLastScore` will be blank... good question btw  @OtoShavadze

Comment: Student may  have only one `cat_id` and  `sub_cat_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query seems to be a bit of complicate, here I do choose to use more less joins to do this:

```
select
    (
        select t1.score_in_per
        from tbl_student_skill_score t1
        where t1.user_email = t.user_email
        and t1.cat_id = t.cat_id
        and t1.sub_cat_id = t.sub_cat_id
        and t1.id = max(t.id) -- this will get the max(id) record in each group
        limit 1
    ) lastScore,
    (
        select t1.score_in_per
        from tbl_student_skill_score t1
        where t1.user_email = t.user_email
        and t1.cat_id = t.cat_id
        and t1.sub_cat_id = t.sub_cat_id
        and t1.id < max(t.id) -- this will get all the record which id less than max(id), then use `order by t1.id desc limit 1`, of course the second last record will be retrieved.
        order by t1.id desc
        limit 1
    ) secondLastScore,
    max(score_in_per) as maxPortaScore,
    user_email, `cat_id`, `sub_cat_id`
from tbl_student_skill_score t
group by `user_email`, `cat_id`, `sub_cat_id`
```

some other joins, you should add them yourself.
And if there is only one record in each group, the `secondLastScore` will be `NULL`.

Comment: it worked like a magic can you please tell me where can i learn all sql topic well..the way you are writing codes looks awesome. thnkx.

Comment: Where to learn, I do not know exactly, if any, I think it is just about more practice, more think, and if you want, here SO also can give you more benifits.@AbdulWaheed

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in three steps: first of all you get the last id and the maximum score for each user

```
select  user_email, max(id) max_id, max(score_in_per) max_score
from    tbl_student_skill_score
group by user_email
```

Then you get the second last id by joining the table with the above query

```
select  t2.max_id, max(id) as second_max, t2.max_score, user_email
from    tbl_student_skill_score t1
right join (
            select  user_email, max(id) max_id, max(score_in_per) max_score
            from    tbl_student_skill_score
            group by user_email
        ) t2
on      t1.user_email = t2.user_email
where   t1.id < t2.max_id
group by user_email
```

Finally you can join all this with the original table to get categories information and the score associated with last and second last id

```
select  t2.score_in_per as lastScore,
        t3.score_in_per as secondLastScore,
        t1.max_score as maxPortaScore,
        t2.user_email,
        t2.cat_id,
        t2.sub_cat_id
from    (
            select  t2.max_id, max(id) as second_max, t2.max_score, user_email
            from    tbl_student_skill_score t1
            right join (
                        select  user_email, max(id) max_id, max(score_in_per) max_score
                        from    tbl_student_skill_score
                        group by user_email
                    ) t2
            on      t1.user_email = t2.user_email
            where   t1.id < t2.max_id
            group by user_email
        ) t1
join    tbl_student_skill_score t2
on      t1.user_email = t2.user_email and
        t1.max_id = t2.id
left join
        tbl_student_skill_score t3
on      t1.user_email = t3.user_email and
        t1.second_max = t3.id
```